# Free RAM keeps decreasing

Tags: raspbian

I've written a python script which can make video's using a Hawkeye camera. While running this script, I feel my Pi gets slower and slower. Besides that, my free RAM shown by the tool 'free' keeps decreasing. Could it be I made some kind of memory leak?

The code i'm using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import time
import hashlib
import signal
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os.path
from os import path
import glob
from shutil import copyfile

REC=20
SWITCH=21
VideoDuration=30

def TestScript():
    GPIO.output(SWITCH, 1)
    while(not path.exists('/media/pi/SDHC')):
        pass
    time.sleep(2)
    GPIO.output(SWITCH, 1)
    LatestVideo = get_latest_file() 
    copyfile("/media/pi/SDHC/Hawkeye/Movie/" + LatestVideo, "/home/pi/Videos/" + LatestVideo)
    while(not path.exists("/home/pi/Videos/" + LatestVideo)):
        pass
    os.remove("/media/pi/SDHC/Hawkeye/Movie/" + LatestVideo)
    time.sleep(2)
    os.system("sudo umount /media/pi/SDHC")
    time.sleep(2)
    GPIO.output(SWITCH, 0)
    time.sleep(3)
    GPIO.output(SWITCH, 1)
    time.sleep(2)
    GPIO.output(SWITCH, 0)
    time.sleep(3)

def get_latest_file():
    fullpath = "/media/pi/SDHC/Hawkeye/Movie/*"
    list_of_files = glob.glob(fullpath)  
    if not list_of_files:                
        return None                      
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
    _, filename = os.path.split(latest_file)
    return filename

def RecordVideo(Duration):
    GPIO.output(REC, 0)
    time.sleep(2)
    GPIO.output(REC, 1)
    time.sleep(Duration)
    GPIO.output(REC, 0)
    time.sleep(2)
    GPIO.output(REC, 1)


###### Execute test script ######
cnt = 0
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(REC, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(SWITCH, GPIO.OUT)
while (cnt < 1000):
## Configure GPIO ##
    START = time.time()
    RecordVideo(VideoDuration-1)
    TestScript()
    cnt = cnt +1
    END = time.time()
    print("Total duration: " + str(END-START))
```

Could it be that I start a process everytime, but never close it?
Could someone please help me out here?

Edit: The output from top can be found below
[image: Output top]
Here is shown that the Pi is running out of free RAM and the cache/buffer is filling with RAM. However I feel the Pi is getting slower and slower. Eventually I get a error in my python script that it's unable to concatenate str and NoneType in the copyfile function. I suspect this happens because the Pi ran out of RAM and can't save the latest filename to the variable LatestVideo anymore.

Thanks in advance

Comment: People are often confused by the way the numbers in `free` add up.   The `free` column excludes page cache, (given by `buf/cache`) which will increase while the system is running; it is perfectly fine to use all the non-`used` memory this way because it can be replaced when needed as quickly as it would otherwise.  The more conventionally meaningful number is given by `available`, which can be significantly more than `free` and is a better reflection of how much memory is available if needed (taken from the page cache).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the original post I added a screenshot of the output of top. Here is shown that the Pi is running out of free RAM and the cache/buffer is filling with RAM. However I feel the Pi is getting slower and slower. Eventually I get a error in my python script that it's unable to concatenate str and NoneType in the copyfile function. I suspect this happens because the Pi ran out of RAM and can't save the latest filename to the variable LatestVideo anymore.

Comment: Nothing in your screenshot suggests your system is short on RAM. You likely have a bug in your code somewhere.

Comment: But there's only 688 MiB free RAM left. Is the buffer/cache RAM also available for use?

Comment: If it is active enough, the page cache *should* start to take the free RAM (see my answer to the duplicate).  It's a performance *enhancement* employed by all contemporary general purpose operating systems. It actually *does not* take "free" memory, because it is still considered **available**.  If a running processes (or new ones that start) need more memory than indicated by the `free` column, that memory is taken out of the cache. This is no more expensive than if it were not being used by anything. *Do not try and eliminate caching, that is not your problem.* What top shows is 100% normal.

Comment: *"But there's only 688 MiB free RAM left."* -> No, you are looking at it wrong.  There is 3906 (total) - 243 (used) = 3663 MB **available**, because the stuff in "buffers/cache" **is not essential**.  It can be dumped/replaced at any point and everything will continue to be fine (if you wan to understand the point of it, read that answer to the dupe).  You have tons of memory left.  Again, emphatically: Memory issues are not causing your problem.